# Is there any way to get notified for new comments even when the user forgot to tag you?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, notifications

I noticed some new activity on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759397/bot-framework-how-to-stop-a-choiceprompt-from-reprompting) that I had been commenting on. I checked my notifications and saw that I hadn't been notified about the latest activity. I had only been notified about the user's previous comment.

[image: Timestamps of comments]

Then I noticed that the reason I wasn't notified about the most recent comment was because I wasn't tagged. My expectation was that I'd automatically be "following" so that I'd be notified about new comments even when I'm not tagged. Is there any way to achieve this functionality, either globally or on a question-by-question basis?

Comment: I think you're not notified because there is one extra participant on that question. Had there only been you and the OP you would have been notified. If this gets implemented I rather have an opt-out as well. On some Meta posts (both here and on MSO) I don't want to get flooded for every new comment that is posted. Inbox Overflow.

Comment: @rene - That's a good observation. I hadn't thought of that.